# Blitting subsurface from tilesheet is doing weird things

Tags: python, pygame

I am coding a prototype platformer in pygame. I'm using a .png as a tilesheet, I load it and then get a list `tileset.tiles` of all the different tile textures in it. I then use three layers of .csv tilemaps to associate every tile in the grid with its own corresponding texture. I bake all of the tile layers onto a `map` surface once, and then blit this surface at every frame.

The problem is that the outcome is not as expected, apparently not all of the tiles are properly blit onto the surface. The problem seems to arise when the same subsurface has to be blit a second time by the `load` method in the `Room` class. It's not clear to me what exactly causes this. I have tried playing around with the .csv files, and it seems that different arrangements of tiles, even across layers, have an influence on what is actually rendered on screen. I've added screenshots to illustrate this better. For reference, the id number 8 corresponds to a blue square texture, which should be the sky. The other numbers correspond to several different textures.

[bottom layer csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv23A.png)

[middle layer csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHhiX.png)

[top layer csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qk1w.png)

[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlzZ.png)

By changing the first tile of the middle layer no difference is shown (tile 0 corresponds to the flower texture):

[alternate middle layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTmf7.png)
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tI9Ga.png)

Or, if I try and change the first few tiles of the bottom layer:

[alternate bottom layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rawDL.png)
[outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9wHg.png)

Generally, if I change some tile number in a csv file, weird things happen, and other seemingly random tiles get blit. Also, I am able to manually place tiles at any position on the screen without any problems (bypassing the `load` method and directly blitting subsurfaces from the `tileset` class) so I think that the `tileset` class is working properly.

Here's the full code:

```
import pygame as pg

class Tileset:

    def __init__(self,img:pg.Surface):
        self.tiles = []
        self.img = img
        self.loadtiles()

    def loadtiles(self):
        for i in range(16):
            for n in range(16):
                currentimg = self.img.subsurface(32*n,32*i,32,32)
                self.tiles.append(currentimg.copy())

class Tile(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,image:pg.Surface,position:tuple):
        self.img = image
        self.pos = position

    def draw (self,surface:pg.Surface): 
        surface.blit(self.img,self.pos)


class Room:
    def __init__(self,id,size:tuple):
        self.id = id
        self.layers = [[],[],[]]
        self.size = (size[0]*32,size[1]*32)


    #   Call when a new room must be loaded: reads room csv, stores tile info, overwrites drawn map with new map

    def load(self,map):

        map = pg.Surface(self.size)

        for layer in self.layers:
            with open ('levels/final/room'+str(self.id)+'_'+str(self.layers.index(layer))+'.csv') as file:
                data = file.readlines()

            for rrrow in data:                           #  unprocessed row
                rrow = rrrow.strip('\n').split(',')      #  semi processed row
                row = []                                 #  processed row

                for rtile in rrow:                       #  unprocessed tile in row

                    if rtile != -1:

                        tileimg = tileset.tiles[int(rtile)]     
                        tile = Tile(tileimg,(rrow.index(rtile)*32, data.index(rrrow)*32))   #   process tile
                        tile.draw(map)                                                      #   draw tile on current tilemap
                        row.append(tile)                                                    #   store tile in row

                layer.append(row)                                                       #   store row in layer (to use later for collisions)

        return map
        

### pygame loop setup (incomplete, shouldn't matter ###

res  = (32*30,32*20)
scr = pg.display.set_mode(res)
tileset = Tileset(pg.image.load('graphics\stock.png'))
room0 = Room(0,(30,20))
map = pg.Surface((0,0))
map = room0.load(map)
running  = True

while running:

    scr.fill((0,0,0))

    scr.blit(map,(0,0))
    pg.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved it. The problem was in the use of the '.index' method to determine what the position of that tile would be. `.index` would just return the first occurrence of that tile in the list, and not the actual one, so any time a tile would have to appear for a second time in the same row, or every time two rows looked the same, that tile/row would just be positioned on top of its previous copy. Solved by using i and n as counters for the tile and row positions instead of the `.index` method.